# Issues with Friendly_ID gem - possible issue with active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I ran the migrations as stated and added this to my model, but I keep generating the following error.  Not really sure what is going on.  My slug column in the photos table is full of unique values as well.

Im running rails 4.

Thanks for any comments in advance.

photo.rb

```
include FriendlyId
friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
```

error in console

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Photo::FriendlyId
    from /Users/jhorsch/Repos/horschgallery2/app/models/photo.rb:4:in `<class:Photo>'
    from /Users/jhorsch/Repos/horschgallery2/app/models/photo.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jhorsch/Repos/horschgallery2/app/admin/photo.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jhorsch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/active_admin-ceb096c5ed4f/lib/active_admin/application.rb:179:in `load'
```

Comment: Have you installed `friendly_id` gem?

Comment: It seems to be working now.  I ended up using the :history instead.

Comment: ' extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :history`

Comment: can you please explain once again?